# 2 Functional Dependencies in a single table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, functional-dependencies

I'm trying to create a schema based on these 2 Functional Dependencies.

> > A -> B, C, D
> >
> > B -> D

I'm trying to create a single table including both of these FDs with the following constraint:

- A pair tuple (B, D) can be repetitive but follows the definition of FD ( whenever there are two B values that are same, then D values are same too).

Now, I have implemented this in 2 tables as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE one(
    B INT PRIMARY KEY,
    D INT NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE (B, D) 
); 

CREATE TABLE two(
    A INT PRIMARY KEY, 
    B INT NOT NULL,
    C INT NOT NULL, 
    D INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(B, D) REFERENCES one(B, D)
);
```

I'm just wondering if there is  a way I can combine these 2 tables in just one table without using **TRIGGERS** in Postgresql?

EDIT:

Example data:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by `combine these 2 tables in just one table`?  Can you give examples of what you want, ideally including example data?  *(I believe I understand the constraints you describe, I just don't understand the last bit...)*

Comment: @MatBailie I mean, instead of creating 2 separate tables, I just want to create one table containing all these attributes. I have edited the post with an example.

Comment: Okay, I think you mean `I just want to create one table containing all these attributes AND enforce all of these constraints without requiring the second table`...

Comment: @MatBailie Your "want" is not clear either; it doesn't say what the "combination" value is in terms of the two tables. jeevaa_v presumably wants their join, which is lossless & satisfies both FDs, instead of the two tables, which are projections of it.

Comment: @philipxy - In the context on my having provided an answer, and that it was accepted, and commented on, I believe it is in fact relatively clear.

Comment: @MatBailie There happens to be one obvious most likely guess for what was wanted. That doesn't mean either of you described it clearly, and neither of you did. ("Natural join" captures what the OP meant by "combine".)

Comment: @philipxy It does, but I thought that was wrong, so I sought clarification that the OP simply meant they wanted to avoid using the second table *(as it only existed for enforcing constraints)*.  And I was right, so I believe that this *has* made it more clear to future readers of this question.  Carrying this on, however, no longer beneficial to future readers of the question, please respond to me in chat if you wish to continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to learn it myself, but I think this is what you want...

```
CREATE EXTENSION btree_gist;

CREATE TABLE fd (
  a    INT PRIMARY KEY,
  b    INT NOT NULL,
  c    INT NOT NULL,
  d    INT NOT NULL,
  EXCLUDE USING gist (b WITH =, d WITH <>)
);
```

An exclude constraint checks all rows against each other, much like a `UNIQUE` constraint checks all rows against each other.  But it's much more generalised.

If all of the checks `(b WITH =, d WITH <>)` are `TRUE` then the row is rejected.

*(Conversely, that means a row is only acceptable if at least one check is `FALSE`.)*

So, if two rows have the same `b` but different `d` the `INSERT` or `UPDATE` that is being run will fail.

http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=5fc308eaaedef4d3d2232ec3d70f3de6

Comment: That's exactly I was looking for. Just to be sure, this is not possible by only using Foreign Key/Unique constraint or Check constraint in Postgresql?

Comment: @jeeva_v Not if you only want one table...  You've already shown how to do it with a foreign key...  The only alternatives are triggers, etc, which all have race-condition issues.

Comment: Also, note that `EXCLUDE` ***is*** effectively a type of `CHECK` constraint.  Just a very flexible one.

Comment: I've only just found it myself *(don't use PostGreSQL much, went on to google to see if it had anything "novel" that would help you)*.   Check this out...  http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=d316a3266d9e1645b626f2d040a7796a

Comment: I'm totally geeking out on EXCLUDE constraints, RANGE types and RANGE operators now.  Thanks for your question, I'd upvote twice if I could :)